# setDynamicLinkDomain is deprecated in code, but doesn't appear to be deprecated in documentation

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

When attempting to use Firebase Dynamic Links to create deep links for Android, I receive an indicator that setDynamicLinkDomain is deprecated (using Android Studio). However, the [tutorial](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/android/create?authuser=0) still uses setDynamicLinkDomain, and neither the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/dynamiclinks/DynamicLink.Builder.html?authuser=0#setDynamicLinkDomain(java.lang.String)) nor the [release notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android) indicate that it is deprecated. I also am unable to find any similar function or other way to set the dynamic link domain.

Does anyone know why this function is deprecated or if it even should be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've had the same issue before so I checked with Firebase support. It appears that the *setDynamicLinkDomain(String)* method was deprecated on version **16.1.1**, please use *setDomainUriPrefix(String)* going forward.

Comment: Disappointing to see that the Firebase documentation has still not been corrected as of Feb 2019 to show the new method and deprecation status of `setDynamicLinkDomain()`.  I sent feedback on the documentation for the errors.

Comment: Also beware that `setDomainUriPrefix()` is not an exact equivalent.  When I replaced `setDynamicLinkDomain()` with `setDomainUriPrefix` and attempted to create a dynamic link from a URI that had a number of parameters (~170 chars long), it failed with exception: `ApiException: 400: Long link is not parsable...`

Comment: @BobSnyder I am having the same issue, how did you resolve this issue?

Comment: @abbujan: I didn't resolve it.  I am continuing to use deprecated `setDynamicLinkDomain()`.  I need to revisit the problem.

Comment: @BobSnyder I found the solution, with `setDomainUriPrefix()` you should always add "https://" before your subDomainLink.

Comment: @BobSnyder How are you using the deprecated setDynamicLinkDomain()? I also need to get this working. I am using dynamic-links16.0.1 and analytics:16.0.1.